# How do you dynamically build navigation in Angular when using lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

Is it possible to build navigation for a header component when all of my routes are stores in route module files using lazy loading?  I have seen articles that build navigation dynamically when all of the navigation is stored in a JSON object or file and they load it all in one shot and build it from there, but none of those articles used lazy loading.  I have an Angular 6 app that uses lazy loading and has quite an extensive navigation structure, and I don't want to hard-code all of the navigation items in the HTML, even though that is not hard to do.  I think it is a more viable option to load the values from a structure and dynamically build the navigation markup with Angulars `*ngFor` directive.  My question is, is this possible with lazy loading?

A little more detail:  my app has an `app-routing.module` and in there is the main route data that tells the app to load the modules, like for example:

```
{ path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule' }
```

So, when a user navigates to `/test`, the `TestModule` is correctly loaded.  I hard-code this route however in the navigation markup of my `header.component`, like this:

```
<a routerLink="test/main">Test</a>
```

Is it possible to build my navigation (`<a>` tags) dynamically with lazy loading in place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a shared component and create a child component with a name eg  `menuItems` inside this menuItems.component.ts file you need to define all of you naviagtion. you will need to create interfaces of what u want to do eg

```
export interface ChildrenItems {
  state: string;
  target?: boolean;
  name: string;
  type?: string;
  children?: ChildrenItems[];
}

export interface MainMenuItems {
  state: string;
  short_label?: string;
  main_state?: string;
  target?: boolean;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  icon: string;
  badge?: BadgeItem[];
  children?: ChildrenItems[];
}

export interface Menu {
  label: string;
  main: MainMenuItems[];
}
```

and other staff as you wish . to get start here is  full sample of menuItems i created long time ago,

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

export interface BadgeItem {
  type: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface ChildrenItems {
  state: string;
  target?: boolean;
  name: string;
  type?: string;
  children?: ChildrenItems[];
}

    export interface MainMenuItems {
      state: string;
      short_label?: string;
      main_state?: string;
      target?: boolean;
      name: string;
      type: string;
      icon: string;
      badge?: BadgeItem[];
      children?: ChildrenItems[];
    }

    export interface Menu {
      label: string;
      main: MainMenuItems[];
    }

    const MENUITEMS = [
      {
        label: 'Navigation',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'dashboard',
            short_label: 'D',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-home',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'default',
                name: 'Default'
              },
              {
                state: 'ecommerce',
                name: 'Ecommerce'
              },
              {
                state: 'crm',
                name: 'CRM'
              },
              {
                state: 'analytics',
                name: 'Analytics',
                badge: [
                  {
                    type: 'info',
                    value: 'NEW'
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                state: 'project',
                name: 'Project'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'widget',
            short_label: 'W',
            name: 'Widget',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-view-grid',
            badge: [
              {
                type: 'danger',
                value: '100+'
              }
            ],
            children: [
              {
                state: 'static',
                name: 'Widget Statistic'
              },
              {
                state: 'data',
                name: 'Widget Data'
              },
              {
                state: 'chart',
                name: 'Widget Chart'
              },
              {
                state: 'advanced',
                name: 'Widget Chart Advcance'
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'UI Element',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'basic',
            short_label: 'B',
            name: 'Basic Components',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-layout-grid2-alt',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'alert',
                name: 'Alert'
              },
              {
                state: 'breadcrumb',
                name: 'Breadcrumbs'
              },
              {
                state: 'button',
                name: 'Button'
              },
              {
                state: 'accordion',
                name: 'Accordion'
              },
              {
                state: 'generic-class',
                name: 'Generic Class'
              },
              {
                state: 'tabs',
                name: 'Tabs'
              },
              {
                state: 'label-badge',
                name: 'Label Badge'
              },
              {
                state: 'typography',
                name: 'Typography'
              },
              {
                state: 'other',
                name: 'Other'
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'advance',
            short_label: 'A',
            name: 'Advance Components',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-crown',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'modal',
                name: 'Modal'
              },
              {
                state: 'notifications',
                name: 'Notifications'
              },
              {
                state: 'notify',
                name: 'PNOTIFY',
                badge: [
                  {
                    type: 'info',
                    value: 'New'
                  }
                ]
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'animations',
            short_label: 'A',
            name: 'Animations',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-reload rotate-refresh'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Forms',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'forms',
            short_label: 'F',
            name: 'Form Components',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-layers',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'basic-elements',
                name: 'Form Components'
              }, {
                state: 'add-on',
                name: 'Form-Elements-Add-On'
              }, {
                state: 'advance-elements',
                name: 'Form-Elements-Advance'
              }, {
                state: 'form-validation',
                name: 'Form Validation'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'picker',
            short_label: 'P',
            main_state: 'forms',
            name: 'Form Picker',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-pencil-alt',
            badge: [
              {
                type: 'warning',
                value: 'New'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'select',
            short_label: 'S',
            main_state: 'forms',
            name: 'Form Select',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-shortcode'
          },
          {
            state: 'masking',
            short_label: 'M',
            main_state: 'forms',
            name: 'Form Masking',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-write'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Tables',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'bootstrap-table',
            short_label: 'B',
            name: 'Bootstrap Table',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-receipt',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'basic',
                name: 'Basic Table'
              }, {
                state: 'sizing',
                name: 'Sizing Table'
              }, {
                state: 'border',
                name: 'Border Table'
              }, {
                state: 'styling',
                name: 'Styling Table'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'data-table',
            short_label: 'D',
            name: 'Data Table',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-widgetized',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'basic',
                name: 'Basic Table'
              }, {
                state: 'editable',
                name: 'Editable'
              }, {
                state: 'row-details',
                name: 'Row Details Table'
              }, {
                state: 'paging',
                name: 'Paging Table'
              }, {
                state: 'selection',
                name: 'Selection Table'
              }, {
                state: 'other',
                name: 'Other Table'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Chart And Map',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'charts',
            short_label: 'C',
            name: 'Charts',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-bar-chart-alt',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'google',
                name: 'Google'
              }, {
                state: 'echart',
                name: 'E-Chart'
              }, {
                state: 'chart-js',
                name: 'ChartJS'
              }, {
                state: 'knob',
                name: 'Knob'
              }, {
                state: 'peity',
                name: 'Peity'
              }, {
                state: 'radial',
                name: 'Radial'
              }, {
                state: 'sparklines',
                name: 'Sparklines'
              }, {
                state: 'c3-js',
                name: 'C3 JS'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'map',
            short_label: 'M',
            name: 'Maps',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-map-alt',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'google',
                name: 'Google'
              }, {
                state: 'vector',
                name: 'Vector'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'landing',
            short_label: 'L',
            name: 'Landing Page',
            type: 'external',
            icon: 'ti-mobile',
            target: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Pages',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'authentication',
            short_label: 'A',
            name: 'Authentication',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-id-badge',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'login',
                type: 'sub',
                name: 'Login Pages',
                children: [
                  {
                    state: 'with-bg-image',
                    name: 'With BG Image',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-header-footer',
                    name: 'With Header Footer',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-social',
                    name: 'With Social Icon',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-social-header-footer',
                    name: 'Social With Header Footer',
                    target: true
                  }
                ]
              }, {
                state: 'registration',
                type: 'sub',
                name: 'Registration Pages',
                children: [
                  {
                    state: 'with-bg-image',
                    name: 'With BG Image',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-header-footer',
                    name: 'With Header Footer',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-social',
                    name: 'With Social Icon',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'with-social-header-footer',
                    name: 'Social With Header Footer',
                    target: true
                  }, {
                    state: 'multi-step',
                    name: 'Multi Step',
                    target: true
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                state: 'forgot',
                name: 'Forgot Password',
                target: true
              },
              {
                state: 'lock-screen',
                name: 'Lock Screen',
                target: true
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'maintenance',
            short_label: 'A',
            name: 'Maintenance',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-settings',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'error',
                name: 'Error'
              },
              {
                state: 'coming-soon',
                name: 'Coming Soon'
              },
              {
                state: 'offline-ui',
                name: 'Offline UI',
                target: true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'user',
            short_label: 'U',
            name: 'User Profile',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-user',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'profile',
                name: 'User Profile'
              }, {
                state: 'card',
                name: 'User Card'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'App',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'crm-contact',
            short_label: 'C',
            name: 'CRM Contact',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-layout-list-thumb'
          },
          {
            state: 'task',
            short_label: 'T',
            name: 'Task',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-check-box',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'list',
                name: 'Task List'
              }, {
                state: 'board',
                name: 'Task Board'
              }, {
                state: 'details',
                name: 'Task Details'
              }, {
                state: 'issue',
                name: 'Issue List'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Extension',
        main: [
          {
            state: 'editor',
            short_label: 'E',
            name: 'Editor',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-pencil-alt',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'froala',
                name: 'Froala WYSIWYG'
              }, {
                state: 'quill',
                name: 'Quill'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'invoice',
            short_label: 'I',
            name: 'Invoice',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-layout-media-right',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'basic',
                name: 'Invoice'
              }, {
                state: 'summary',
                name: 'Invoice Summary'
              }, {
                state: 'list',
                name: 'Invoice List'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'file-upload',
            short_label: 'F',
            name: 'File Upload',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-cloud-up'
          },
          {
            state: 'change-log',
            short_label: 'C',
            name: 'Change Log',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-list',
            badge: [
              {
                type: 'warning',
                value: '1.0'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Other',
        main: [
          {
            state: '',
            short_label: 'M',
            name: 'Menu Levels',
            type: 'sub',
            icon: 'ti-direction-alt',
            children: [
              {
                state: '',
                name: 'Menu Level 2.1',
                target: true
              }, {
                state: '',
                name: 'Menu Level 2.2',
                type: 'sub',
                children: [
                  {
                    state: '',
                    name: 'Menu Level 2.2.1',
                    target: true
                  },
                  {
                    state: '',
                    name: 'Menu Level 2.2.2',
                    target: true
                  }
                ]
              }, {
                state: '',
                name: 'Menu Level 2.3',
                target: true
              }, {
                state: '',
                name: 'Menu Level 2.4',
                type: 'sub',
                children: [
                  {
                    state: '',
                    name: 'Menu Level 2.4.1',
                    target: true
                  },
                  {
                    state: '',
                    name: 'Menu Level 2.4.2',
                    target: true
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            state: 'simple-page',
            short_label: 'S',
            name: 'Simple Page',
            type: 'link',
            icon: 'ti-layout-sidebar-left'
          }
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'Support',
        main: [/*
          {
            state: 'documentation',
            short_label: 'D',
            name: 'Documentation',
            type: 'external',
            icon: 'ti-file',
            target: true
          },*/
          {
            state: 'submit-issue',
            short_label: 'S',
            name: 'Submit Issue',
            type: 'external',
            icon: 'ti-layout-list-post',
            target: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    @Injectable()
    export class MenuItems {
      getAll(): Menu[] {
        return MENUITEMS;
      }

      /*add(menu: Menu) {
        MENUITEMS.push(menu);
      }*/
    }
```

edit the code above acording to your need, after that ur shared module.ts should look like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MenuItems} from './menu-items/menu-items';
...........................


@NgModule({
  imports: [
.............
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [......],
  exports: [
...........
    NgsModule,

  ],
  providers: [ MenuItems ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and app.module.ts something like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AppRoutes} from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './layout/admin/admin.component';
import {ClickOutsideModule} from 'ng-click-outside';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {BreadcrumbsComponent} from './layout/admin/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component';
import {TitleComponent} from './layout/admin/title/title.component';
import {AuthComponent} from './layout/auth/auth.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    TitleComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
    ClickOutsideModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

from here you will get what U want if I understood your question good luck